# Angular chip textbox (chip list) is overlapped by the popup with the possible values

Tags: ios, angular

Testing my Angular chip code on iPhone SE the possible values list overlaps the textbox where the value is typed into (I can still write into it though), but on desktop and Android it works just fine, the list is either above or below the textbox.

Code:

```
<mat-form-field class="full-width">
    <mat-label>Buildings</mat-label>
    <mat-chip-grid #chipGrid aria-label="Building selection">
        <mat-chip-row *ngFor="let aBuilding of buildings" (removed)="remove(aBuilding)">
            {{ displayBuildingName(aBuilding) }}
            <button matChipRemove [attr.aria-label]="'remove'">
                <mat-icon>cancel</mat-icon>
            </button>
        </mat-chip-row>
        <input placeholder="Add building" #buildingInput [formControl]="buildingCtrl"
            [matChipInputFor]="chipGrid" [matAutocomplete]="auto" />
        <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" (optionSelected)="selected($event)">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let aBuilding of filteredBuildings | async" [value]="aBuilding">
                {{ displayBuildingName(aBuilding) }}
            </mat-option>
        </mat-autocomplete>
    </mat-chip-grid>
</mat-form-field>
```

[image]

Any help is appreciated!